# How to print Hindi words in NLTK's Indian corpus?

Tags: python, unicode, nlp, nltk

Code:

```
from nltk.corpus import indian

nltk.corpus.indian.words('hindi.pos')
```

Output:

```
[u'\u092a\u0942\u0930\u094d\u0923', u'\u092a\u094d\u0930\u0924\u093f\u092c\u0902\u0927', ...]
```

But, I need output to be: `['पूर्ण', 'प्रतिबंध', 'हटाओ', ':', 'इराक', 'संयुक्त', ...]`
Like shown in: http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html

Could you please tell how can I print the actual words instead of unicode.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Seems like this is Py2K, no unicode literals by default (try printing those strings)

Comment: When I use print nltk.corpus.indian.words('hindi.pos'), the output is the same.

Comment: What if you print just one?

Comment: Thank you so much. I am able to print now.

Comment: Try `print nltk.corpus.indian.words('hindi.pos')`

Comment: print u'\u092a\u0942\u0930\u094d\u0923' prints the word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 2 doesn't have VM-wide Unicode support. The prettyprinter isn't the same as printing one of the strings in the array -- but printing just one will work as expected.